# how to add class 'active' on menu anchor when the menu is included wih php

Tags: php, jquery, include

My situation: 
I have several pages like `home.php`, `about.php`, `gallery.php` ...
In all these pages i include the menu with the anchors with php. so the menu is not in the pages. In all the pages i have the line: `include('includes/menu.php');`
What i want to achieve: if url is `mydomain.com /gallery.php` the anchor in the menu should have an extra class like `"active"` so i can style it different (current page is open).

I tried it with jquery:
I gave all the anchors a class `"clickable"` like below:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
     <li><a class="clickable" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a class="clickable" href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>                        
     <li><a class="clickable" href="openingtimes.php">Openingtimes</a></li>
 </ul>
```

And load this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
      $(".clickable").click(function() { 
      $(this).addClass("active");      //add the class to the clicked  element
      });
   });
});
```

But the problem that appears: when click on the anchor, lets say `gallery.php`, it gets the class "active' shortly but the gallery.php is loading and the menu is again included via php. Ofcourse, this works only if you stay on the same page.

What can i do best with this situation to make an anchor active when the specific page is loaded? 
Maybe read the url and then on basis of this url add a class to the anchor?

Comment: check out your super globals $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Try using:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a class="clickable <?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/index.php') { echo "active"; } ?>" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="clickable <?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/gallery.php') { echo "active"; } ?>" href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="clickable <?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/openingtimes.php') { echo "active"; } ?>" href="openingtimes.php">Openingtimes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also make sure if the file is in another directory to add the name ex. `if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/folder/index.php')`

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I agree. This is the most easy solution for this problem. Thanks

Comment: No Problem, Cheers!